# Is it possible to read the Pass Type ID in app at runtime?

Tags: ios6, passbook

I have a piece of code needs to be shared by multiple apps. I need to use the Pass Type ID to check if a certain Pass is always in user's Passbook app. To check it I need to use Pass Type ID.  Is it possible to read the Pass Type ID used in the app at runtime?

Something to fill ... in the following line.

```
        NSString* passTypeID = ... ; //How to get the passTypeID at runtime?
        for (PKPass *passFromPassbook in [PKPassLibrary passes]) {

        if ([[passFromPassbook passTypeIdentifier] isEqualToString:passTypeID]
            && [[passFromPassbook serialNumber] isEqualToString:serialNumber]) {
            isPassAlreadyInPassbook = YES;
            break;
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Each app will need to be compiled with permissions for the passTypeID(s) that is needs to access, so why not set each ID as a constant? You can only access passes which have been signed by a certificate that you control, you cannot access third party passes.  If you are trying to access your own passes, can you provide more info on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @PassKit, thank you for your reply. I have two apps and I want to use the same piece of code. I know I can put the PassTypeID into configuration. Just want to see if there's better solution.